# VBA-PowerPoint text/font shadow via macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make text in the data label of the chart with shadow effect (that shadow effect which you have at top of the PowerPoint menu), but I'm unable to make it work, `dataLabels.shadow` or `dataLabels.font.shadow`  makes the frame shadowed, not the text.

I was googling a lot, I have found out this could be possible via `TextFormat` or `TextFormat2` property, unfortunately I'm not able to access it for the text in the data label anyhow. My current code, lines after comment does not work:

```
For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
    If Shape.HasChart Then

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim v As Variant

        Set pts = Shape.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points

        For Each s In Shape.Chart.SeriesCollection
            v = s.Values
            If s.Name <> "XXX_XXX" Then
                If v(pts.Count) >= 0.05 Then
                    s.Select
                    s.Points(pts.Count).Select
                    s.Points(pts.Count).ApplyDataLabels
                    s.DataLabels.Font.Color = s.Border.Color
                    s.DataLabels.Font.Size = 20
                    s.DataLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                    's.DataLabels.Shadow = True 
                    's.DataLabels.Font.Shadow = msoTrue 
                    's.Points(pts.Count).DataLabel.Font.Shadow = msoTrue
                    's.Points(pts.Count).DataLabel(pts.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Shadow = msoTrue                                                   
                End If
            End If
        Next s
    End If
Next Shape
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone will have problems with simillar case I have found the answer :)

The shadow (ribbon like shadow) for data label text/value is done via `TextRange2` property, but I was missing `Format`. Like this :

```
Dim tr As TextRange2 
Set tr = s.DataLabels(pts.Count).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
With tr.Font.Shadow
  .OffsetX = 10
  .OffsetY = 10
  .Size = 1
  .Blur = 4
  .Transparency = 0.5
  .Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: First of all, set ".Visible = True " , or  you won't get the shadow you want.